# Call callback in redux action (with redux-promise as a middleware)

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm using `redux` and `redux-promise` in my action function:

```
export function createGroup(values, callback) {
  const request = axios.post(GROUP_ENDPOINT,
    {
      name: values.name,
      description: values.description
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  ).then((response) => callback(response)); // <--- HERE
  return {
    type: NEW_GROUP,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default function(state=INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case NEW_GROUP:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.data.id]: action.payload.data};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I call the callback function in the action function, I receive undefined in the reducer.

Is it possible not to use `redux-thunk` but still fix this issue ? Is it possible to have two handlers attached so when the data comes back, both get called ?

Comment: I'm a little confused, the action should be dispatched AFTER the request has been processed. This means that you can dispatch it in the `.then` function. You don't even need any middleware to be honest to achieve this, you can simply initiate an ajax call in your component and after it resolves, you can dispatch one or more actions inside `.then`. Otherwise you can use `redux-thunk`.

Comment: I can show you a couple examples if you need me to, are you specifically tied to `redux promise` ?

Comment: I prefer to use `redux-promise`, as it neatly resolves the promises and there is no need for `.then`, etc. I know (I didn't tryi it yet) that it should be fixed by using `redux-thunk`, but I was trying to avoid it so far.